# Excel 2010 scrollbar goes too far

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, scrolling, scrollbar

My problem is illustrated in the PrintScreen below:

[image]

I've searched a lot on the Internet and almost all sources say to delete the empty rows at the end of the sheet and save the document. For example that is what is suggested [here](http://www.contextures.com/xlfaqApp.html#Unused) (see Section 2f).

Sometimes this works, but most of the time it doesn't!

I don't know if this is relevant information or not, but my Excel document contains three user-defined macros, including two that have to do with comments formatting. There are many comments in the sheet "Notes A", most of them with pictures as backgrounds. Also, my document is not protected, so I do not think the problem is that the extra lines are locked.

**Is there a definitive solution to this?**

**Added:** Here are the codes of my three macros.

**Module 1:** This is a macro that sorts alphabetically the string of letters of a word. For example, applying it to a cell containing HELLO will give EHLLO as the output.

```
Option Compare Text
Function SortString(ByVal iRange, Optional Croissant As Boolean = True)
'Trevor Shuttleworth, mpep, modifié fs, mpfe
Dim i%, j%, sTemp$
For j = 1 To Len(iRange) - 1
 For i = 1 To Len(iRange) - 1
  If Mid(iRange, i, 1) > Mid(iRange, i + 1, 1) Then
   sTemp = Mid(iRange, i, 1)
   Mid(iRange, i, 1) = Mid(iRange, i + 1, 1)
   Mid(iRange, i + 1, 1) = sTemp
  End If
 Next
Next

If Croissant = False Then
 For i = Len(iRange) To 1 Step -1
  SortString = SortString & Mid(iRange, i, 1)
 Next
 Exit Function
End If

SortString = iRange

End Function
```

**Module 2:** This is a macro that automatically resizes comments containing words.

```
Sub Fitrangecomments()
'Updateby20140325
Dim rng As Range
Dim WorkRng As Range
xTitleId = "KutoolsforExcel"
Set WorkRng = Application.Selection
Set WorkRng = Application.InputBox("Range", xTitleId, WorkRng.Address, Type:=8)
For Each rng In WorkRng
    If Not rng.Comment Is Nothing Then
        rng.Comment.Shape.TextFrame.AutoSize = True
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

**Module 3:** This is a macro that asks the user to choose a background image for a to-be-created comment and that automatically resizes the comment to match the image dimensions.

```
Sub InsertComment()

    Dim strImagePath As Variant
    Dim objImage As Object

    strImagePath = Application.GetOpenFilename("Picture, *.jpg; *.png; *.bmp")
    If strImagePath = False Then Exit Sub

    Set objImage = CreateObject("WIA.ImageFile")
    objImage.LoadFile strImagePath

    With ActiveCell
        If .Comment Is Nothing Then .AddComment ("")
        .Comment.Shape.Fill.UserPicture strImagePath
        .Comment.Shape.Height = objImage.Height * 0.75
        .Comment.Shape.Width = objImage.Width * 0.75
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You've likely diagnosed your own problem.  The user defined macro's are probably white space, that you then reset using the technique at the link you provided.  No one will be able to help unless you show those macro's as part of the question.

Comment: @Tyson I've added the codes of the macros I use.

Answer (score 0):

What range are you calling that SortString function on? If it's looping through the entire sheet then that might explain your issue. Consider using a named range, or else embed a 'Count' function so it only runs on rows which have been populated.

Not going to ask about the Croissant...